# Howto identify UTF-8 encoded strings

Tags: unicode, encoding, utf-8

What's the best way to identify if a string (is or) might be UTF-8 encoded? The Win32 API `IsTextUnicode` isn't of much help here. Also, the string will not have an UTF-8 BOM, so that cannot be checked for. And, yes, I know that only characters above the ASCII range are encoded with more than 1 byte.

Comment: What is the language your trying this in ?

Comment: Doesn't really matter - I'm looking for a general method. But if you can give something that works for a particular language, then please chime in.

Comment: And, thou shall not find a BOM at the begining of an UTF-8 stream, it makes no sense as UTF-8 is the same whatever the byte order is.

Comment: Yes, but it's still called "BOM" by some. I prefer to call it "preamble" (as .NET) or "signature". It can still be useful for the purpose of identifying the encoding.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[chardet](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/intl/chardet.html) character set detection developed by Mozilla used in FireFox. [Source code](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla/source/intl/chardet/)

[jchardet](http://jchardet.sourceforge.net/) is a java port of the source from mozilla's automatic charset detection algorithm.

[NCharDet](http://www.conceptdevelopment.net/Localization/NCharDet/) is a .Net (C#) port of a Java port of the C++ used in the Mozilla and FireFox browsers.

[Code project C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/DetectEncoding.aspx) sample that uses Microsoft's [MLang](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767865(VS.85).aspx) for character encoding detection.

[UTRAC](http://utrac.sourceforge.net/)  is a command line tool and library written in c++ to detect string encoding

[cpdetector](http://cpdetector.sourceforge.net/link.shtml) is a java project used for encoding detection

[chsdet](http://chsdet.sourceforge.net/) is a delphi project, and is a stand alone executable module for automatic charset / encoding detection of a given text or file.

Another useful post that points to a lot of libraries to help you determine character encoding http://fredeaker.blogspot.com/2007/01/character-encoding-detection.html

You could also take a look at the related question [How Can I Best Guess the Encoding when the BOM (Byte Order Mark) is Missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373081/how-can-i-best-guess-the-encoding-when-the-bom-byte-order-mark-is-missing), it has some useful content.

Comment: Sorry to comment on a 10 year old answer but I have a minor correction. cpdetector is not a Delphi library (it's written in Java). If anyone is looking for Delphi encoding detection, it might be worth looking into [chsdet](https://sourceforge.net/projects/chsdet/).

Comment: @AdamHenderson thanks for the correction, i've updated the question

Answer (score 7):

There is no really reliable way, but basically, as a random sequence of bytes (e.g. a string in an standard 8 bit encoding) is very unlikely to be a valid UTF-8 string (if the most significant bit of a byte is set, there are very specific rules as to what kind of bytes can follow it in UTF-8), you can try decoding the string as UTF-8 and consider that it is UTF-8 if there are no decoding errors.

Determining if there were decoding errors is another problem altogether, many Unicode libraries simply replace invalid characters with a question mark without indicating whether or not an error occurred. So you need an explicit way of determining if an error occurred while decoding or not.

Comment: Any _proper_ Unicode library should replace unknown characters with [U+FFFD](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm), not with a literal question mark.

Answer (score 6):

[This W3C page](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-forms-utf-8) has a perl regular expression for validating UTF-8

Comment: If you're reading a stream and you might not have the beginning, you should either loose the \A at the begining or add a ".{0,5}?" just after it to capture the first truncated character.

Comment: I would recommend doing this by using the language's standard Unicode library rather that reimplementing it through regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify a language, but in PHP you can use `mb_check_encoding`

```
   if(mb_check_encoding($yourDtring, 'UTF-8'))
   {
   //the string is UTF-8
    }
   else 
    {
       //string is not UTF-8
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

For Win32, you can use the mlang API, this is part of Windows and supported from Windows XP, cool thing about it is that it gives you statistics of how likely the input is to be in a particular encoding:

```
CComPtr<IMultiLanguage2> lang;
HRESULT hr = lang.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CMultiLanguage, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER);
char* str = "ï»¿abc"; // EF BB BF 61 62 63
int size = 6;
DetectEncodingInfo encodings[100];
int encodingsCount = 100;
hr = lang->DetectInputCodepage(MLDETECTCP_NONE, 0, str, &size, &encodings, &encodingsCount);
```

Comment: I've just made a few tests of the DetectEncodingInfo() routine, and the results are very poor:  

* It can't distinguish between French texts in CP 437 and CP 1252, even though the text is completely unreadable if opened in the wrong code page.  

* It can detect text encoded in CP 65001 (UTF-8), but not text in UTF-16, which is wrongly reported as CP 1252 with good confidence!

Answer (score 1):

To do character detection **in ruby** install the 'chardet' gem

```
sudo gem install chardet
```

Here's a little ruby script to run chardet over the standard input stream.

```
require "rubygems"
require 'UniversalDetector' #chardet gem
infile =  $stdin.read()
p UniversalDetector::chardet(infile)
```

Chardet outputs a guess at the character set encoding and also a confidence level (0-1) from its statistical analysis

[see also this snippet](http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/159-Detecting-file-data-encoding-with-Ruby-and-the-chardet-RubyGem)

Answer (score 1):

C/C++ standalone library based on Mozilla's character set detector

https://github.com/batterseapower/libcharsetdetect

> Universal Character Set Detector (UCSD)
>   A library exposing a C interface and dependency-free interface to the Mozilla C++ UCSD library.  This library provides a highly accurate set of heuristics that attempt to determine the character set used to encode some input text. This is extremely useful when your program has to handle an input file which is supplied without any encoding metadata.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, you can use `MultiByteToWideChar()` with the `CP_UTF8` codepage and the `MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS` flag.  If the function fails, the string is not valid UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

As an add-on to the previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19308773/2215591) about the Win32 mlang DetectInputCodepage() API, here's how to call it in C:

```
#include <Mlang.h>
#include <objbase.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ole32.lib")

HRESULT hr;
IMultiLanguage2 *pML;
char *pszBuffer;
int iSize;
DetectEncodingInfo lpInfo[10];
int iCount = sizeof(lpInfo) / sizeof(DetectEncodingInfo);

hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
hr = CoCreateInstance(&CLSID_CMultiLanguage, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, &IID_IMultiLanguage2, (LPVOID *)&pML);
hr = pML->lpVtbl->DetectInputCodepage(pML, 0, 0, pszBuffer, &iSize, lpInfo, &iCount);

CoUninitialize();
```

But the test results are very disappointing:

- It can't distinguish between French texts in CP 437 and CP 1252, even though the text is completely unreadable if opened in the wrong code page.
- It can detect text encoded in CP 65001 (UTF-8), but not text in UTF-16, which is wrongly reported as CP 1252 with good confidence!

Comment: Of course, it's just the minimal code necessary. You have to integrate in your own valid function.