# How to avoid inadvertent encoding of UTF-8 files as ASCII/ANSI?

Tags: utf-8, notepad++, byte-order-mark

In the process of editing a file encoded as UTF-8 w/o [spurious] BOM the content might become devoid of any Unicode characters outside the ASCII or ANSI ranges. At the next reopening of the file, some text editors (Notepad++) will interpret it as ASCII/ANSI encoded and open it as such. Unaware of the change the user will continue editing, now adding non-ANSI Unicode characters, rendered however useless, since saved in ANSI. A menu option can exist (Notepad++) to open ANSI files as UTF-8 w/o BOM, but leading to the reverse issue of inadvertently overriding ANSI files with Unicode encoding.

Comment: Why do you say that BOM is "spurious"?

Comment: "For UTF-8, the encoding scheme consists merely of the UTF-8 code units (= bytes) in sequence. Hence, there is no issue of big- versus little-endian byte order for data represented in UTF-8. However, for 16-bit and 32-bit encoding forms, byte serialization must break up the code units into two or four bytes, respectively, and the order of those bytes must be clearly defined." (Unicode Book, p. 36, http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode5.0.0/ch02.pdf)

Adding BOM to UTF-8 (MS Notepad in UTF-8) is a hack to allow for a distinction of UTF-8 content.

Comment: Because it distinguishes UTF-8, maybe it's truthful and useful (not spurious).

Comment: Yes, until it becomes a problem. In my case there were web applications not working until the BOM was removed. See various other issues in the third paragraph of the Usage section in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte-order_mark. Terminology wise the use of BOM bytes sequence for identifying UTF-8, would be better expressed as "signature" or "preamble" as mentioned by Johann Gerell in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377294/howto-identify-utf-8-encoded-strings.

Answer (score 2):

One workaround is to add a character outside the ANSI range to a comment in the file. Depending on the decoding algorithm, it might force the editor (Notepad++) to recognize the file as encoded in UTF-8 w/o BOM.

In a HTML document for example you could follow the charset definition in the header with such a Unicode comment, here the U+05D0 HEBREW LETTER ALEF:
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> <!-- א -->

Answer (score 2):

How would you suggest that an editor tell the difference between ASCII/ANSI and UTF-8 w/o BOM, when the files look the same?

If you want guaranteed recognition of UTF-8 as UTF-8, either add the BOM, or force the file to contain UTF-8 characters.

Comment: Hi Anon.! Sorry, I didn't get the reply to my own question uploaded fast enough for you to see in time. The solution was what you suggested.

Comment: Many text editors (for example, Notepad++) are good at detecting non-ASCII UTF8 compatible symbols in files and, based on that, assume the files are UTF8. There are some sane approaches to do that, although there is always a risk to misdetect some exotic codepage for UTF8.

Answer (score 2):

Configure your editor to always use UTF-8 if possible, if not, complain to the creators of your editor. Charsets not targeting unicode are, IMO, deprecated and should be treated as such.

Files using only characters in the ASCII space (the 7-bit one) would be pretty much the same in UTF-8 anyway, so if you HAVE to deliver something in ASCII encoding, just don't type any unicode characters.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I found fascinating in this issue is that a file can change its physical status (encoding) if the information it carries (a text) is modified (using during one edit words in the non-ASCII Unicode ranges and during another happening to use only words made from ASCII charcters). It is a bit like a pen that would suddenly change its colors according to the words you write.