# Generate UTF-8 file with NotesStream

Tags: utf-8, lotus-notes, lotusscript

I'm trying to export some text to an UTF-8 file with LotusScript. I checked the documentation and the following lines should output my text as UTF-8, but Notepad++ says it's ANSI.

```
Dim streamCompanies As NotesStream
Dim sesCurrent as New NotesSession

Set streamCompanies = sesCurrent.CreateStream
Call streamCompanies.Open("C:\companies.txt", "UTF-8")
Call streamCompanies.WriteText("Test")
streamCompanies.Close
```

When I try the same with UTF-16 instead of UTF-8, the generated fileformat is correct. Could anyone point me in the right direction on how to write an UTF-8 file with LotusScript on a Windows platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notes is most likely doing its job and encoding properly.  It is likely that Notepad++ is interpreting the UTF-8 file as ANSI if no UTF-8-only characters exist in the file.  There is no other way to determine the encoding in this case other than to analyze its contents.

See this SO answer:  [How to avoid inadvertent encoding of UTF-8 files as ASCII/ANSI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924521/how-to-avoid-inadvertent-encoding-of-utf-8-files-as-ascii-ansi)

So a simple test to make sure Notes is working would be to output a non-ANSI character and then open in Notepad++ to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Closed - down the line while coding I stumbled across some data with Asian characters which where displayed correctly in my text editor. Rechecking file encodings I found the following:

If the output text only includes ASCII-chars, it is decoded as ANSI with Notepad++
If the output text contains e.g. Katakana, it is decoded as UTF-8 with Notepad++

-> problem solved for me.

Comment: I wouldn't say this is closed.  It's a good question and will save others from the same confusion.

Comment: Have to agree with Ken, it's bound to help someone else. It's fine to accept your own answer too.

Comment: Yes of course, but I have to wait a few days before I am able to accept my own answer :-)