# How to identify file format of a file with out BOM (UTF8 No BOM or ANSI)?

Tags: utf-8, ansi, byte-order-mark

I need to identify  files with UTF8 with out BOM/ ANSi format from a set of files. How can I identify these files format? Currently using strategy is check whether the file format is belongs to any already known formats(Having BOM) if not declare as UTF8/ANSI. Is there any direct method to find these formats?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Howto identify UTF-8 encoded strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377294/howto-identify-utf-8-encoded-strings)

Comment: UTF8 is not ANSI (and ANSI is not really ANSI, it is just a bad name interpreted in the wrong way).

Answer (score 0):

The usual method works:

- Check for BOM, and read the file according format given by BOM. If you have error (or not BOM) go to next point
- Assume it is UTF8, and read the file accordingly. If you have errors, go to next point. It is very seldom to have a false positive (non-UTF8 file which is also correct UTF8)
- Assume the file is Latin1 or CP1252 (*ANSI*, which is a superset of Latin1)

This is the easier way and most safe. With other methods (detection), you should still implement additionally also such method, because you may fail to read a file with detected encoding.

Remember that BOM strings could be in real *ANSI* files, as real characters, and unfortunately there are files which uses different encodings (e.g. various source codes, they may have in copyright, some name in some encoding, but comments in other encoding.

If you want to implement a better algorithm, after point 1, check code `00`. If there are some (or many), fallback with UTF-32 (if there are 3 consecutive `00`), or UTF16LE or BE depending if most `00` are in even (LE) or odd position. Ignore/substitute illegal combinations.