# How does Python xml parser detect encoding (utf-8 vs utf-16)?

Tags: python, xml, character-encoding, elementtree, expat-parser

The Python XML Parser can parse byte strings of various encodings (Even if there is no encoding specified in the XML header):

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

xml_string = '<doc>Glück</doc>'

xml_utf_8 = xml_string.encode('utf-8')
xml_utf_16 = xml_string.encode('utf-16')

print(ET.fromstring(xml_utf_8).text)
print(ET.fromstring(xml_utf_16).text)
```

Output:

```
Glück
Glück
```

**Questions:**

- Is it safe to let the parser detect the correct encoding (utf-8 vs. utf-16, other encodings fail if not specified in the parser)?
- The detection seems to be done in the expat C library. How does it reliably detect the right encoding?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12349728/elementtree-and-unicode

Comment: According to this answer, it should default to utf-8, whenever there is no encoding specified in the xml header (This would be the correct behavior according to xml specification). But as I show in the example above, it detects that the second byte-string is utf-16 and the parser does not fall back to utf-8.

Comment: The Expat documentation has [a whole chapter explaining this mechanism.](https://libexpat.github.io/doc/expat-internals-encodings/), though understanding it requires a fair amount of knowledge about the library's internals.

Comment: I guess that the parser detects the byte order mark in the case of UTF-16.

Comment: Perhaps see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/377306/874188

Answer (score 0):

The code to detect the encoding in Expat is in [function `initScan` in file `xmltok.c`](https://github.com/libexpat/libexpat/blob/a39a2f5c6538c6bd1715e6f2a77b81fe1d84fa89/expat/lib/xmltok.c#L1530C5-L1530C5) at the moment and it is inspecting individual bytes and is e.g. comparing them to the [byte order marks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) known for little endian UTF-16, big endian UTF-16 and UTF8; null bytes also play a part.  To find the places where the code makes a final decision about an encoding, you could do this on a Git clone of Expat:

```
# git --no-pager grep -F '= encodingTable[UTF'
lib/xmltok.c:      *encPtr = encodingTable[UTF_16BE_ENC];
lib/xmltok.c:      *encPtr = encodingTable[UTF_16LE_ENC];
lib/xmltok.c:      *encPtr = encodingTable[UTF_16LE_ENC];
lib/xmltok.c:        *encPtr = encodingTable[UTF_8_ENC];
lib/xmltok.c:        *encPtr = encodingTable[UTF_16BE_ENC];
lib/xmltok.c:        *encPtr = encodingTable[UTF_16LE_ENC];
```