# Guessing the encoding of text represented as byte[] in Java

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

Given an array of bytes representing text in some unknown encoding (usually UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1, but not necessarily so), what is the best way to obtain a guess for the most likely encoding used (in Java)?

Worth noting:

- No additional meta-data is available. The byte array is literally the only available input.
- The detection algorithm will obviously not be 100 % correct. If the algorithm is correct in more than say 80 % of the cases that is good enough.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373081/ maybe of help

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The following method solves the problem using [juniversalchardet](http://code.google.com/p/juniversalchardet/), which is a Java port of Mozilla's encoding detection library.

```
public static String guessEncoding(byte[] bytes) {
    String DEFAULT_ENCODING = "UTF-8";
    org.mozilla.universalchardet.UniversalDetector detector =
        new org.mozilla.universalchardet.UniversalDetector(null);
    detector.handleData(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    detector.dataEnd();
    String encoding = detector.getDetectedCharset();
    detector.reset();
    if (encoding == null) {
        encoding = DEFAULT_ENCODING;
    }
    return encoding;
}
```

The code above has been tested and works as intented. Simply add [juniversalchardet-1.0.3.jar](https://code.google.com/archive/p/juniversalchardet/downloads) to the classpath.

I've tested both [juniversalchardet](http://code.google.com/p/juniversalchardet/) and [jchardet](http://jchardet.sourceforge.net/). My general impression is that juniversalchardet provides the better detection accuracy and the nicer API of the two libraries.

Comment: my project requirement is if the data is not in utf8 (after detection) then convert it to utf8, how to do this ?

Comment: @coding_idiot use the "guessed" encoding to convert to a String then get utf-8 bytes: `new String(bytes, guessedEncoding).getBytes("utf-8")`.

Comment: Not very happy with this. See https://github.com/albfernandez/juniversalchardet/issues/22

Comment: juniversalchardet is also available in maven. groupId: com.googlecode.juniversalchardet, artifactId: juniversalchardet.

Answer (score 5):

There is also [Apache Tika - a content analysis toolkit](http://tika.apache.org/). It can guess the mime type, and it can guess the encoding. Usually the guess is correct with a very high probability.

Answer (score 4):

Here's my favorite: https://github.com/codehaus/guessencoding

It works like this:

- If there's a UTF-8 or UTF-16 BOM, return that encoding.
- If none of the bytes have the high-order bit set, return ASCII (or you can force it to return a default 8-bit encoding instead).
- If there are bytes with the high bit set but they're arranged in the correct patterns for UTF-8, return UTF-8.
- Otherwise, return the platform default encoding (e.g., windows-1252 on an English-locale Windows system).

It may sound overly simplistic, but in my day-to-day work it's well over 90% accurate.

Answer (score 1):

Chi's answer seems most promising for real use. I just want to add that, according to Joel Spolsky, Internet Explorer used a frequency-based guessing algorithm in its day:

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Roughly speaking, all the assumed-to-be-text is copied, and parsed in every encoding imaginable. Whichever parse fits a language's average word (and letter?) frequency profile best, wins. I can not quickly see if jchardet uses the same kind of approach, so I thought I'd mention this just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [jchardet](http://jchardet.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Please elaborate - why do you consider jchardet to be the best library around?

Comment: @chi how to convert to utf8 if the encoding is not utf8.

Answer (score -1):

Should be stuff already available

google search turned up icu4j

or

http://jchardet.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I kind of know how to use Google, but the question specifically asks for "what is the best way [..]". So which is best, icu4j, jchardet or some other library?

Answer (score -1):

Without encoding indicator, you will never know for sure. However, you can make some intelligent guesses. See my answer to this question,

[How to determine if a String contains invalid encoded characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887148/how-to-determine-if-a-string-contains-invalid-encoded-characters)

Use the validUTF8() methods. If it returns true, treat it as UTF8, otherwise as Latin-1.

Comment: What about the cases where it is not UTF-8?

Comment: If it's not UTF-8, blindly calling it Latin-1 isn't a good idea.  It would be better to use ICU, jchardet, or one of the other tools listed on this page to make an intelligent guess.