# java string base64 encoded

Tags: java, string, base64

I need a way to know if a string is Base64 encoded... 
any idea ?

thanks

Comment: take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677497/guessing-the-encoding-of-text-represented-as-byte-in-java/1678810#1678810

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string length hast to be a multiple of 4 and only the following characters are allowed
**A-Z, a-z, 0-9** **+**, ****/ and **=** as padding character (only at the end)

Answer (score 4):

IMHO you need to try to decode it, and if it fails - it is not encoded.

There are many Base64 decoders for Java, here are some:

`sun.misc.BASE64Decoder`

[Apache codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/)

http://migbase64.sourceforge.net/

http://www.source-code.biz/base64coder/java/