# How is this file encoded?

Tags: encoding, character-encoding

I have a .csv file generated by Excel that I got from my customer. My software has to open and parse it in java. I'm using [universalchardet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1678810/334493) but it did not detect the encoding from the first 1,000 bytes of the file.

Within these 1,000 first bytes, there is a sequence that should be read as `Boîte`, however I cannot find the correct encoding to use to convert this file to UTF-8 strings in java.

In the file, `Boîte` is encoded as `42,6F,94,74,65` (read using a hex editor). `B`, `o`, `t` and `e` are using the standard latin encoding with 1 byte per character. The `î` is also encoded on only one byte, 0x94.

I don't know how to guess this charset, none of my searches online yielded relevant results.

I also tried to use `file` on that file:

```
$ file export.csv
/Users/bicou/Desktop/export.csv: Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with CR line terminators
```

However I looked at the extended-ASCII charset, the value `0x94` stands for `ö`.

Have you got other ideas for guessing the encoding of that file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was [Mac OS Roman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_Roman) encoding. When using the following java code, the text was properly decoded:

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(targetFileName), "MacRoman");
```

I don't know how to delete my own question. I don't think it is useful anymore...

Comment: It's actually very informative. Thank you for finding it out.