# Java - Convert byte[] to String without knowing the character encoding

Tags: java, string, encoding, character, arrays

I'm receiving a byte[] of information in an unspecified encoding format. Is there a way to convert it to a String without knowing the character encoding?

Comment: See [Guessing the encoding of text represented as byte\[\] in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677497/guessing-the-encoding-of-text-represented-as-byte-in-java). Almost a duplicate and certainly will help.

Comment: Glad it helped. It's not a perfect duplicate, but since it answered your question and is very closely related, I'm happy to close this question.

Answer (score 1):

The tool of choice is CharsetMatch from ICU: http://userguide.icu-project.org/conversion/detection

It is not an exact science, so there is a confidence score that you have to watch and it will take some experimentation, but will definitely get you where you want to go.  Good Luck!