# Reverse Parse Multi-Byte

Tags: java, data-structures, bit

I want to determine whether the last character in the buffer defined as the bytes between begin and end is English or Japanese. I read about uTF-8 where Japanese characters are two bytes long and always have 1 in the high bit of the high byte, whereas low byte can have either 1 or 0 in the high bit.

I am trying to return integer 2 for Japanese(2Bytes), 1 for English and  0 for data in buffer is malformed.

public static int NumChars(byte begin, byte end).
Can you point me to the right direction? I am confused how to approach this. I was thinking about using xor to find if the MSB in high bit is 1 then return 2, but I have a doubt even if I understood correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Jeevan UTF-8 character byte length can be between 1 to 4 bytes.

so If you want to print 2 for Japanese characters please use this unicode.

[SJIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_JIS)

Example:--

```
String j = "大";     
System.out.println(j.getBytes("SJIS").length);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a discussion about this on this thread [guessing-the-encoding-of-text-represented-as-byte-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677497/guessing-the-encoding-of-text-represented-as-byte-in-java)

If you can get the buffer or part of it in string form. Then you can use regular expressions to match the character sets like this:

```
   String english = ".*[\\x{20}-\\x{7E}]$";
   String hiragana = ".*[\\x{3041}-\\x{3096}]$";
   
   byte[] buffer = {97, 98, 99, -29, -127, -126}; //"abcあ"
   System.out.println("buffer: "+Arrays.toString(buffer));
   String s = new String(buffer,"utf-8") ;

   System.out.println(s + " is hiragana=" + s.matches(hiragana));
   System.out.println(s + " is english=" + s.matches(english));

   s = "abcd";
   System.out.println(s + " is hiragana=" + s.matches(hiragana));
   System.out.println(s + " is english=" + s.matches(english));
```

Output:

```
buffer: [97, 98, 99, -29, -127, -126]
abcあ is hiragana=true
abcあ is english=false
abcd is hiragana=false
abcd is english=true
```

You will have to find out which Japanese character sets your program is using like Kenji, Hiragana, Katakana etc.
For more information read this article: [regular-expressions-for-japanese-text](http://www.localizingjapan.com/blog/2012/01/20/regular-expressions-for-japanese-text/)