# How to detect the character encoding of a text file using Delphi?

Tags: delphi, character-encoding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I detect the encoding/codepage of a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90838/how-can-i-detect-the-encoding-codepage-of-a-text-file)
>   [How Can I Best Guess the Encoding when the BOM (Byte Order Mark) is Missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373081/how-can-i-best-guess-the-encoding-when-the-bom-byte-order-mark-is-missing)

I would like to know if there are some delphi libraries for the purpose of detecting the character encoding of a text file.

Comment: I think you may want to read [how-can-i-detect-the-encoding-codepage-of-a-text-file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90838/how-can-i-detect-the-encoding-codepage-of-a-text-file). If the text file has a `BOM`, read it, otherwise it is not generally possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my comment there was a link to [how-can-i-best-guess-the-encoding-when-the-bom-byte-order-mark-is-missing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/373081/576719) which may work for you if the text files have no `BOM`.

Look at the [Charset Detector library](http://chsdet.sourceforge.net/) and try it out.
It will try to read the `BOM` and if it's not there make a best effort guess.

Comment: I fixed the URL so as you wouldn't miss any eventual oppurtunity to earn `Announcer`, `Booster`, `Publicist` publicity badges :-)

Comment: What delphi versions are supported by the Charset Detector library?

Comment: I looked at the source code, but I can't tell for sure.